# Is my comma usage correct in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, clauses

"*When there is too much carbon in the atmosphere, too much heat is trapped from the Sun’s light rays, dramatically increasing the global temperature.*"

Answer (score -1):

To my mind the use of 'light rays' should be changed to 'infra-red rays' as light implies visible, whereas infra-red rays are not actually visible, being below the wavelengths of the visible spectrum, hence 'infra'.

The sentence could be written thus:
The global temperature is dramatically increased when too much heat from the Sun's infra-red emissions is trapped by excessive amounts of carbon in the atmosphere.

However, your use of commas is not strictly wrong, but it gives a kind of clunky sentence where the clauses don't fit together well.